# System keeps scanning hard disk partition for errors every boot

Tags: boot, 15.10

There is no file `/forcefsck`, and the disk partition is clean. Yet it fsck runs on the partition every boot, and it takes forever.

```
Last mounted on:          /home
Filesystem UUID:          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              52346880
Block count:              209356288
Reserved block count:     10467814
Free blocks:              131834845
Free inodes:              50775457
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      974
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Filesystem created:       Mon Apr  1 21:06:59 2013
Last mount time:          Tue Dec  1 13:50:24 2015
Last write time:          Tue Dec  1 13:50:24 2015
Mount count:              11
Maximum mount count:      31
Last checked:             Tue Dec  1 13:22:49 2015
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          1534 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       22997232
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      81f59ef5-027c-4b6d-9fbc-014e0483994a
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

The file system scan stops for a while at 95 %, but running fsck from emergency prompt works.

Answer (score 0):

The number of reboots per fsck parameter is set on the hard drive. Use tune2fs to change the parameter:

```
sudo tune2fs -c 0 /dev/yourhdd
```

Comment: If I understand it right, this parameter tells it to fsck every 31 mount, but the current mount count is less then 31, so it should not do it yet.